# OpenMP Extremeley High CPU Usage and Comparision other Library

Tags: c++, performance, concurrency, multiprocessing, openmp

I am working on a multiprocessing application using OpenMP. My code base is very simple. Operating point cloud message in ROS callback, cloud size is fix when callback each call. When I run code sequentially, each operation takes 35 ms, and the CPU usage is about ~%35. However, when a I run the code with OpenMP, the processing time is very unstable: it's around 20-45 ms and the CPU usage is very high, like %300 (16 thread * 20). I think OpenMP generates the maximum number of threads, according to Amdahl's law high number of thread causing performance overhead. If, I am correct, is there any way of setting a constant number of threads?
How can I optimize CPU usage and the run time when OpenMP is used?

Instead of using OpenMP, I tried to perform a simple operation with C++17 execution and the Thrust library with the TBB backend. The run time and the CPU usage was very stable.

In the originial code base, there are a little bit complex operation. For more understanding, i simplified code base and this piece of code getting same result:

```
// cloud->points.size() ~ 150000

// OpenMp , Runtime 0.1 ms  - 1.85 ms (~0.6)    Cpu usage (%25 - %30 )
void callback(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2::ConstPtr &cloud){

#pragma omp parallel shared{

#pragma omp for
   for(int i=0 ; i< cloud->points.size() ; i++){simple_operation();}

}
}

// Single thread, Runtime ~ 0.2 ms    Cpu usage (%5 - %6 )
void callback(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2::ConstPtr &cloud){

   for(int i=0 ; i< cloud->points.size() ; i++){
      simple_operation();
   }

}

//Thrust with TBB backend, Runtime ~ 0.15 ms    Cpu usage (%6 - %7 )
void callback(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2::ConstPtr &cloud){

  thrust::for_each(thrust::tbb::par,
                   cloud->begin(),
                   cloud->end(),
                   simple_operation());

}


//C++ 17 execution policy, Runtime ~ 0.15 ms    Cpu usage (%6 - %7 )
void callback(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2::ConstPtr &cloud){

  std::for_each(
      std::execution::par_unseq,
      cloud_in->begin(),
      cloud_in->end(),
      simple_operation());

}
```

`simple_operation()` is dummy operation for testing. In this sample, i used;

```
void simple_operation(Point point){

      double distance = std::sqrt(std::pow(point.x, 2) *
          std::pow(point.y, 2) *
          std::pow(point.z, 2));

}
```

Comment: How many cores does your machine has?

Comment: 0.15ms is too short to measure cpu time reliably. Let the tests run longer, on the order of 1..5s.

Comment: it has 8 cores , 16 thread.

Comment: As advice by @rustyx I would test your code with a bigger input so that you can get values in seconds

Comment: In the original code base, i compared single thread and openmp result. It takes around 30-50 ms with sample result. I simplified for sample code.

Comment: I edited the post to make it a bit more clear/readable but I still do not fully understand your point regarding the Amdahl's law or the "thread size". Can you please clarify this point and also provide a more information about the code?  (for example you can provide the code for `simple_operation`, the actual value for `cloud->size()` and change the code so it can be a valid C++ code).

Comment: @JérômeRichard , Thanks for the help. Edited my question.

Comment: Can you add the compiler you use and the optimization flags? If optimizations are enabled, `simple_operation` will be discarded since it does not have visible effects. In such a case, you are probably measuring noise (like the time to create the threads).

Comment: @JérômeRichard I am using -g3 -O3 flags, but I tried with different flags.Optimizations are enabled.   `simple_operation` just simplified for my problem, only this piece of code comsuming %30 cpu, each thread consuming %1 ~ 3 . if I do more complex operations instead `simple_operation`, CPU usage is getting too high. In the original code, sequentially processing takes %30 CPU usage, but when used OpenMP, it takes %300 cpu usage. In the other hand, TBB balances CPU usage.

Comment: The problem here is the code you provide is not representative of the code on which you have the actual issue. So we cannot reproduce the same issue and thus it is hard for us to help you. That being said, if you want OpenMP to load balance the work better, you can just add the clause `schedule(dynamic)` to the for loop (you might also want to control the granularity, see the OpenMP documentation for more information).

Comment: I am tried schedule(dynamic) with different chunk size. unfortunately, it didn't work. Thanks for advice, i will check more deeply.

Comment: I think, this problem is not case specific. For this purpose, i simplified code base.

Comment: It could be that OpenMP starts worker threads on-demand, and other solutions on program startup. Make the test run longer, to amortize any startup time. It could also be that the data is cached after the first run, which makes other runs faster. Or it could be that simple_operation() is optimized away entirely for lack of side-effects. Since we can't reproduce it as the question lacks a [mcve], we can only guess. Hence, I'm out of here...